# Nvidia not showing both video cards

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

Im running Ubuntu 11.10.

I installed the nvidia drivers version "current version" and they are installed correctly and currently in use - this is what the Additional Drivers program tells me.

I go to the Nvidia control program, and I find information about the video card.
Except that I have two video cards and there's only one listed.

When I use the command line program lshw, I can clearly see that the kernel recognizes that there are two GPU connected:

```
id: 
pci:0
description:    PCI bridge
product:    NF200 PCIe 2.0 switch for mainboards
vendor:     nVidia Corporation
physical id:    
0
bus info:   
pci@0000:02:00.0
version:    a2
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pci pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration:  
driver  =   pcieport
resources:   irq    :   0 ioport    :   c000(size=4096)
memory  :   ea000000-edffffff ioport    :   d0000000(size=268435456)

    id: 
    display
    description:    VGA compatible controller
    product:    G92 [GeForce 8800 GTS 512]
    vendor:     nVidia Corporation
    physical id:    
    0
    bus info:   
    pci@0000:03:00.0
    version:    a2
    width:  64 bits
    clock:  33MHz
    capabilities:   pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration:  
    driver  =   nvidia
    latency =   0
    resources:  
    irq :   16
    memory  :   ec000000-ecffffff
    memory  :   d0000000-dfffffff
    memory  :   ea000000-ebffffff
    ioport  :   cf00(size=128)
    memory  :   ed000000-ed01ffff

id: 
pci:1
description:    PCI bridge
product:    NF200 PCIe 2.0 switch for mainboards
vendor:     nVidia Corporation
physical id:    
2
bus info:   
pci@0000:02:02.0
version:    a2
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pci pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration:  
driver  =   pcieport
resources:  
irq :   0
ioport  :   b000(size=4096)
memory  :   e6000000-e9ffffff
ioport  :   c0000000(size=268435456)

    id: 
    display
    description:    VGA compatible controller
    product:    G92 [GeForce 8800 GTS 512]
    vendor:     nVidia Corporation
    physical id:    
    0
    bus info:   
    pci@0000:04:00.0
    version:    a2
    width:  64 bits
    clock:  33MHz
    capabilities:   pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration:  
    driver  =   nvidia
    latency =   0
    resources:  
    irq :   16
    memory  :   e8000000-e8ffffff
    memory  :   c0000000-cfffffff
    memory  :   e6000000-e7ffffff
    ioport  :   bf00(size=128)
    memory  :   e9fe0000-e9ffffff
```

Now, why isnt the NVidia software showing information on both video cards?

Thank you in advance, for your time and help.
jenia

EDIT:

this is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file

```
Section "Device"

    Identifier  "Default Device"

    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"

EndSection
```

As you see, my xorg.conf file does not contain any information as indicated by Periera. So tried to remove this above shown section and replace it with the information provided by Bruno Periera; however, my visual interface stopped working on logout.
I then decided instead of replacing, to append the Bruno Periera's information to the information orignally contained (show above) in the xorg.conf file. No effect was observed. That is, the visual interface works fine, but the second card was not listed by Nvidia's control program.

Answer (score 2):

For dual card setup you need to specify another device in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

Open the file with your favorite text editor, let say using `gedit`:

> gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

You should have something like this at the moment:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Driver          "nvidia"
    BusID           "PCI:0:03:0"
EndSection
```

Where `BusID           "PCI:0:03:0"` is one of your cards, what you need to do is duplicate that entry for the 2nd card so that it looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Driver          "nvidia"
    BusID           "PCI:0:3:0"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Screen1"
    Driver          "nvidia"
    BusID           "PCI:0:4:0"
EndSection
```

That should force the driver to be loaded to your first card in `BusID           "PCI:0:03:0"` and your second card in your `BusID           "PCI:0:04:0"`.

Comment: Can you please add that to your question? That way the information is available to everyone without having to read these comments.

Comment: yes sure. its posted there.